# Add references of selected elements From ListA to ListB

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have two List: List ListA, and ListB(the type of ListB is where I am confused).

Further, ListA contains {1,2,3}; Obviously  ListA[0] is 1, ListA[1] is 2, and ListA[3] is 3.

What I am trying to do is like this:
add the reference of ListA[0], whose value is 1, to the ListB.

The result that I expect is that once the ListA[0] changed to other number(e.g. 5), the only element that was added from ListA to ListB should be changed to 5 automatically. I had tested it for several times based on solutions referenced from the Internet, but got errors/not working properly.

=========================================================================
Below is the code that I am using after following the post() that was the closest to what I wanted, but got wrong output.

```
    List<int> ListA;*emphasized text*
    List<Ref<int>> ListB;


    ListA = new List<int>();
    ListA.Add(1);
    ListA.Add(2);
    ListA.Add(3);

    ListB = new List<Ref<int>>();



    Ref<int> one = new Ref<int> { Value =  ListA[2] };

    ListB.Add(one);

    ListA[0] = 5;


    foreach (int i in ListA)
    {
        Debug.Log("ListA: " + i);
    }



    foreach (Ref<int> i in ListB)
    {
        Debug.Log("ListB: " + i.Value);
    }



public class Ref<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output of the above code is: 
ListA: 5
ListA: 2
ListA: 3
ListB: 1
The expected outcome should be:
ListA: 5
ListA: 2
ListA: 3
ListB: 5

What should I do to make it right? I appropriate any helps and inspirations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, ListA also need to contain

```
    Ref<int>
```

instead of

```
    int
```

You can never update a value type (e.g. an int) and expect it to have effect on any other reference than the one you are explicitly updating.
The following does what you need.

```
[TestClass]
public class RefOfIntTest
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void WhenUpdatingReferenceTypeItHasEffectForAllReferences()
  {
    List<Ref<int>> ListA;
    List<Ref<int>> ListB;


    ListA = new List<Ref<int>>();
    ListA.Add(new Ref<int>(1));
    ListA.Add(new Ref<int>(2));
    ListA.Add(new Ref<int>(3));

    ListB = new List<Ref<int>>();



    Ref<int> one = ListA[0];

    ListB.Add(one);

    ListA[0].Value = 5;


    foreach (Ref<int> i in ListA)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("ListA: " + i.Value);
    }

    foreach (Ref<int> i in ListB)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("ListB: " + i.Value);
    }
  }
}


public class Ref<T> where T : struct
{
    public Ref(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I also changed:

```
Ref<int> one = ListA[2];
```

into:

```
Ref<int> one = ListA[0];
```

as it was index 0 that was later updated

Comment: Yes @HariPrasad it just needs to be put into context, Now I have included the method around the main code block so you can just add it to a UnitTest class, add [TestMethod] attribute and run it
Output: 
ListA: 5
ListA: 2
ListA: 3
ListB: 5

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is the behaviour of object not value types. For examples if you had a class :
`public class SomeClass { public int TheProperty {get;set;}}`
Then your expection for the value of `TheProperty` would change in ListB and ListA at the same time. Give that a try and see what you get.

When you move around a value type you're passing around the actual value not the reference to that value as you when when working with an object. The syntax is the same but the implementation on the managed stack is completely different.

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote. I already endorsed your answer in mine one and just forgot to upvote yours. But I am not a hypocrite. So Better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with Peter4499 . The way you want is not possible with value type. The best way to achieve what you want is to use BindingList instead of List then use BindingList's CollectionModified event to update the other list. Every time binding list changes, the event fires and you can use NotifyCollectionChangedEventargs to update the other list. For more information please visit this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs)